# django not reconizing default objects manager for model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, models, attributeerror

I am running my django server and I am getting a 500 code with the error

`AttributeError: type object 'EventPurpose' has no attribute 'objects'`

the model however was created correctly and other models with the same implementation are working fine. Here is the full code from model creation to use.

model creation

```
class EventPurpose(models.Model):
    purpose = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

view

```
class GetAllSettingsObjects(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        eventpurposequeryset = EventPurpose.objects.all()
```

and that is were I get the error: The error in full

```
line 24, in get
    eventpurposequeryset = EventPurpose.objects.all()
AttributeError: type object 'EventPurpose' has no attribute 'objects'
[27/Feb/2018 20:57:55] "GET /<super cool url object that I dont want to share with you>/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16404
```

I still haven't figured this out so here is the full trace back:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/dependancy/suitsadmin/settings/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/virtualsuits/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/virtualsuits/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/virtualsuits/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/virtualsuits/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/virtualsuits/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/virtualsuits/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 494, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/virtualsuits/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 454, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/virtualsuits/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 491, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/backend/virtualsuits/suitsandtables/suitsandtablessettingsapp/views.py", line 24, in get
    eventpurposequeryset = EventPurpose.objects.all()
AttributeError: type object 'EventPurpose' has no attribute 'objects'
[28/Feb/2018 00:52:12] "GET /api/dependancy/suitsadmin/settings/ HTTP/1.1" 500 19430
```

please help.

Hugs and kisses

Comment: did you import EventPurpose? Try to put from .models import EventPurpose in your views.py

Comment: @HenryH yes I imported the models as such since I am using all of them `from models import *`

Comment: looks like you did override EventPurpose some other place

Comment: @Linovia I throughly checked the site and such (assuming Django code is working as intended) its rather frustrating lol

Comment: print some statement such as print(type(EventPurpose)) to see what type it is really. Might be you defined a view named EventPurpose which would void the import.

Answer (score 0):

so I found a solution. This makes no sense to me at all but I alised the `EventPurpose` as `eventpurpose` again no idea why this works and would love a reason.

I got the answer from this question: [type object 'X' has no attribute 'objects'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543695/type-object-x-has-no-attribute-objects)

and here is what I did

```
from models import EventPurpose as eventpurpose
```