# FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'is_active' into field

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I get the above error, when I do following.

```
class UserViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    A viewset for viewing and editing user instances.
    """
    models = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_active=1) # See this
```

My model does contain `is_active` field, and serializer has `fields = '__all__'`.

Do I need to override `get_queryset` method?

**EDIT:**

Following works.  **EDIT** `not working now.`

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return User.objects.filter(is_active=1)  

def get_queryset(self):
    return self.queryset.filter(is_active=1)  


def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(UserViewSet, self).get_queryset()
    return queryset.filter(is_active=1)
```

**All three says** `Cannot resolve keyword 'is_active' into field`.

P.S - Above all three were tried with  `queryset = User.objects.all()`in class

**Models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    login_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    auth_type = models.ForeignKey(AuthType, models.DO_NOTHING)
    user_type = models.ForeignKey('UserType', models.DO_NOTHING)
    user_org = models.ForeignKey('Organization', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, related_name="childs")
    auth_user_id = models.OneToOneField(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column="auth_user_id", related_name='cpeUser')
    user_create_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    user_expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'cpe_user'
```

Comment: If is_active is a boolean field, use 'True' value not '1'

Comment: That is also not working.

Comment: Freak, I got my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35544035/1936024. My viewset name and model name is same. Bloody naive colleague.

Comment: still getting `is_active` error. even in `get_queryset`

Comment: You mean `all()` in `class attribute` and `filter()` in `get_queryset`, right? It is that way only. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting class attribute as

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

And then overriding `get_queryset` method as below:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.queryset.filter(is_active=1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately not... I tried `queryset = super(UserViewSet, self).get_queryset()` too. Still, says `can not resolve is_active into field`

Comment: by the way, it is `generics.ListCreateAPIView` and not `ModelViewSet`. Let me update my question.

Comment: Then I, suspect there's an issue with the User model. Can you post your User model code? Are you sure it's a django.contrib.auth User model?

Comment: Please see the updated question for UserModel. It's not `AuthUser` model, it is an extended table.

Comment: Okay, the issue is with your model field `is_active`. Can you confirm that the row exists on the table and you have run migrations successfully?  And also since your `is_active` acts as an boolean field, you can actually go ahead and convert it into a [Django Boolean Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield). Let me know if it works.

Comment: The thing is, tables are not managed by django. They were created with sql scripts. And it is charfield, and tables contains data tool

Comment: Okay so, could post the entire error printed something that looks like this: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'nama' into a field. Choices are: account, account_id, created_at, created_by, name.....`.

Comment: Yes, it is suggesting all the fields except `is_active`

Comment: Yeah, so I'm pretty sure the column `is_active` does not exist on the User table.

Comment: I am able to filter queryset using other fields except `is_active`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185551/discussion-between-haren-lewis-and-kishor-pawar).