# Django form - custom user

Tags: django, django-forms

I created a custom user in django as it follows:

```
class Customer(AbstractBaseUser):
...
```

in my forms.py I imported the class:

```
from account.models import Customer

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
            
            ...

            client_code = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Customer.objects.all(), required=True,
                    widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={ 'class':'form-select form-select-sm',
                    'aria-label':'Default select example',
            }))

            ...
```

I run the server and this error is shown:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Customer' has no attribute 'objects'
```

The project structure is:

```
account
 -- models.py
 -- forms.py
...


post
 -- models.py
 -- forms.py
...
```

The Error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 423, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/.../dev/.../src/post/urls.py", line 42, in <module>
    path('post/', include('post.urls')),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/.../dev/project/src/post/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .views import (
  File "/.../dev/project/src/post/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .forms import PostForm
  File "/.../dev/project/src/post/forms.py", line 13, in <module>
    class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/.../dev/project/src/post/forms.py", line 80, in PostForm
    cliente_code = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Customer.objects.all(), required=True,
AttributeError: type object 'Customer' has no attribute 'objects'
```

Comment: can you post full error trace back

Comment: might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543695/type-object-x-has-no-attribute-objects